# How to select rows with specific date from a data frame

Tags: r

I wanna get all purchases made during January and February of 2008, here is my code. I have no idea what's wrong with it. Can anyone help?

```
mydf1$Purchase.Date<-as.Date(mydf1$Purchase.Date, "%m/%d/%Y")

a<-subset(mydf1, mydf1[(Purchase.Date >= "2008-01-01" & Purchase.Date <= "2008-02-28")])
```

[image: dataframe]

Comment: Please provide the result of `dput(mydf1)` such that we can reproduce your results

Comment: The result is the original dataframe. Nothing has changed

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting an error message? Or just an unexpected output? Please update the question to reflect your situation.

You could try using the `filter` function in `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
mydf1 <- mydf1 %>%
  filter(Purchase.Date >= "2008-01-01" & Purchase.Date <= "2008-02-28")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

`a <- df[mydf1$Purchase.Date >= "2008-01-01" & mydf1$Purchase.Date <= "2008-02-28",]`